# how to handle click and focus events to toggle ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have requirements, when user clicks, I need to show or hide a section and on focus need to show then on blur need to hide.

I am trying to bind three events,

```
$(btn).on({click:toggle,focus:show,blur:hide});

var isOpen = false;
function toggle(){
if(!isOpen)show();
else hide();
}
function show(){
isOpen = true;
//my code to show
}

function hide(){
isOpen = false;
//my code to hide
}
```

but click and focus events conflicting..

how to make it work with the both events focus and click?

Comment: What does "click and focus events conflicting" mean?

Comment: Use jQuery `bind()`, [http://api.jquery.com/bind/](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: After you click on something, that sets the focus there, too.

Comment: @SreelalPMohan The first line of the description says _As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method_

Comment: How would the user set the focus if they don't click?  Using the tab key?  If the section is already hidden, how is it going to get the focus, and if it's not hidden, why do you need to show it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey focus and click calling same time its causing to hide the section

Comment: @Barmar first focus and click calling

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think he's hiding the same thing he's clicking on.

Comment: @KongaRaju I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Please paste (or describe) the specific errors you're receiving

Answer (score 0):

You can bind both 'click', 'focus', 'blur' events to button:

```
var btn = $("#btn");
btn.on('click', function() { 
    $("#testElement").toggle('slow');
});
btn.on('focus', function() {
    $("#testElement").show('slow');
});
btn.on('blur', function() {
    $("#testElement").hide('slow');
});
```

Here is [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivangrs/xe4bvxnp/)